# How to write regex to match Donorbox EmbedForm?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, angular9

I need to build a Regex rule that must validate if a value match a Donorbox Embed Form. This to ensure the user input codes really comes from Donorbox.

An example of Donorbox EmbedForm:

```
<script src="https://donorbox.org/widget.js" paypalExpress="false"></script>
<iframe src="https://donorbox.org/embed/..." allowpaymentrequest="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The regex needs to know if their is a script and iframe tags, then look at both src tags to validate the domain.

What I did so far:

```
<textarea (change)="donorBoxEmbedFormVerification(e)" type="text"></textarea>
        
donorBoxEmbedFormVerification(embedHtml: string):boolean {
   // need some help
   console.log(embedHtml.match('<\s*script[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*script>'));
   return true;
}
```

Any help about the regex would be appreciate,

Regards,

Samantha

Comment: Please provide some fail cases too i.e. the strings on which the code fails. It'll help

Comment: I do not know how to write such a regex.

Comment: Looks like a good start. I'm testing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to match all such HTML form elements which contains `src` attribute which has `donorbox` as a sub-string. For this case; you may try:

```
^(?=.*src="https:\/\/donorbox\.org.*).*
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^`** - Represents start of the line.
- **`(?=.*src="https:\/\/donorbox\.org.*)`** - Represents a positive look-ahead asserting `src` attribute to be equal to `https://donorbox.org`.
- **`.*`** - **Greedily** matching everything zero or more times.

#### Regex Demo